# UI-Router (resolve) cant pass data into controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

when i run code like this my controller stops working and it happens with all kinds of data passed with resolve, from api or any other way.. i just cant pass anything to my controller

```
> $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/movies')
>                 $stateProvider
>                         .state('movies', {
>                                 url: '/movies',
>                                 templateUrl: 'templates/movies.html',
>                                 controller: 'indexCtrl',
>                                 resolve: {
>                                         resolveParam: function(){
>                                                  return 'sdsadasdasd'
>                                                 }
>                                 }
>                         })
> 
>         }]);
> 
> 
>         app.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolveParam',              function($scope, resolveParam) {
>                $scope.click = function() {
>                         alert();
> 
> 
> 
>                 }
>         }]);
```

as long as i run it like this, it works perfectly fine

```
app.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
           $scope.click = function() {
                    alert();
            }
    }]);
```

even if my state still looks same like above..

Comment: Your resolve needs to return a promise.

Comment: then it should be working like this            
http://pokit.org/get/img/9968e3ce68f6d8e13d7b4c35c66a5b9b.jpg but it doesnt

Comment: is there an error on the stack trace?

Comment: just frontend app, working in VS Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a typo, or some other hard-to-trace error. 
JSfiddle based on your code is working just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/vcx171qa/

JS

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/movies')
    $stateProvider
      .state('movies', {
        url: '/movies',
        template: '<div>{{resolveParam}}</div>',
        controller: 'indexCtrl',
        resolve: {
          resolveParam: function() {
            return 'sdsadasdasd';
          }
        }
      })

  }])

.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolveParam', function indexCtrl($scope, resolveParam) {
  $scope.resolveParam = resolveParam;
}]);
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
   </body>
</html>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: ahh yea probably, didnt have time to figure it out so i made http request inside of controller method.. anyways thanks guys